# How to deal with addressbook changes

Tags: iphone, ios, addressbook, data-synchronization

In our app we keep references to contacts in the address book. What is the best way to make sure that we can deal with updates (both from our app to the address book as well as from the address book to our app).

We want to make sure we can handle spelling mistakes, address phone and email changes, synchronization, duplication, 'interesting' use of first last and company name etc.

Currently we check first on addressbook id. Only if it changes, we update our information/try to find back the contact. This is not good enough.

Answer (score 1):

JPContactArchive https://github.com/joepasq/JPContactArchive will auto-update an app's internal record of a contact if their phone number or email has changed. It assumes a somewhat orderly address book; it does not handle duplicates, relying on the user to pick the correct one.

Comment: Thanks. This is somewhat comparable to our current implementation.

Comment: If there's anything else you need from the project, ask. As always there's the ability to fork it also.

Comment: @JoePasq the repo link is broken. Did you move to other repo or it's no longer existing?