# how to check and retrieve changed/newly added contact details from address book in iOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c

In my app I am getting all address book data. But when I start app next time I just want to retrieve modified/newly added contacts in address book.

Can you please suggest me any possible ways?

Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to deal with addressbook changes](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8432234/how-to-deal-with-addressbook-changes/8432391#8432391)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get notified in contact changed event in IOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29208605/how-to-get-notified-in-contact-changed-event-in-ios)

Answer (score 8):

From iOS 9 you can register your class to observ *CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification*:

**Obj-C code:**

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(addressBookDidChange:) name:CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

And then:

```
-(void)addressBookDidChange:(NSNotification*)notification
{
  //Handle event here...
}
```

**Swift code:**

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(
    self,
    selector: "addressBookDidChange:",
    name: CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification,
    object: nil)
```

And then:

```
@objc func addressBookDidChange(notification: NSNotification){     
    //Handle event here...
}
```

as reported in [Contacts Framework Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/Contacts/Reference/Contacts_Framework/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40015328)

> After a save is successfully executed, the contact store posts a
>   CNContactStoreDidChangeNotification notification to the default
>   notification center. If you cache any Contacts framework objects you
>   need to refetch those objects, either by their identifiers, or with
>   the predicates that were used to originally fetch them, and then
>   release the cached objects. Note that cached objects are stale, but
>   not invalid.

Comment: how track the deleted/modified/added contact ID ? Thank you !!

Comment: @Chathuranga how to track deleted/modified/added contact ID ?... please help me .. i want to only get update contact ... we are faceing last 4 days.. but not getting any proper solutions... please help me

Comment: I think it's not possible with new iOS, We need to manage it internally by checking each item :(

Comment: how? ... please give me solutions

Comment: notification is called when new contact is added but do not get any information of new contact or update contact.

Comment: @Deepesh did you find any unique id to get new contact while contact getting updated?

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a method that checks the address book for updated phone numbers or emails of contacts; specifically only contacts the user added but there's nothing stopping one from extending it to all contacts.

It's called [JPContactArchive](https://github.com/joepasq/JPContactArchive) and the method you'll want to check out is [`-updateContacts`](https://github.com/joepasq/JPContactArchive/blob/master/JPContactArchive/JPContactArchiveViewController.m#L163). It should help.

Comment: first time when i launch app i want retrieve all contacts but at second time i want retrieve only modified and newly added contacts. Now I have taken all contacts in dictionary and all dictionary objects putted into array.

Comment: given link is not working.please provide proper link.